# Is there an way to assign a variable inside a loop's conditional expression?

Tags: syntax, rust

Is there an equivalent to this C expression in Rust?

```c
int x;
while ((x = get_num()) < 5) {
    printf("x is %d, but less than 5\n", x);
}
```

`get_num()` is a function that takes user input and returns an integer.

The best I've been able to come up with so far is this:

```
while let Some(x) = {let y = get_num(); if y < 5 {Some(y)} else {None}}  {
    println!("x is {}, but less than 5", x);
}
```

Comment: Is that actually a valid C expression…?

Comment: Yes, C compilers even have a warning to make sure you put extra parenthesis around the assignment to make sure you didn't mean == instead of =. It's called -Wparenthesis https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: @Ry- Clearly, no it isn't a valid C expression, (but I wish it would sometime ;))

Comment: I see the error now. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Rust 1.28, you can use [`iter::repeat_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.repeat_with.html):

```
for x in iter::repeat_with(get_num).take_while (|x| *x < 5) {
    println!("x is {}, but less than 5", x);
}
```

but boring is probably better:

```
loop {
    let x = get_num();

    if x >= 5 {
        break;
    }

    println!("x is {}, but less than 5", x);
}
```

[Eventually, there might](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2497) be an equivalent closer in syntax.

```
// doesn’t exist yet!
while let x = get_num() && x < 5 {
    println!("x is {}, but less than 5", x);
}
```

Comment: Oh my, those are some gnarly for loop iterators. I agree, boring is better.